# How to rebuild a graph on an html page based on the result of selecting data in the wtform form in a web-application?

Tags: flask, html5-canvas, flask-wtforms

I am developing a web application in flask. The application has a database. When the user visits the page, he should see a graph with default data for the first device. Then there are filters in which the user selects the desired device, data type and time period. After clicking on the "Apply" button, the graph should be rebuilt according to the user's choice. Filters are made in wtform. The graph builds a canvas script in html. Problem: The graph is not rebuilt, it remains the original default all the time

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/chart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chart_view():
    """Chart Page"""
    form = LogChartForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        source_id = form.source_id.data
        type_id = form.type_id.data
        time_start = form.time_start.data
        time_end = form.time_end.data
        source_get = EvSource.query.filter_by(description=source_id).first()
        source = source_get.id_ev_source
        if type_id != 'All':
            typ_get = EvType.query.filter_by(description=type_id).first()
            typ = typ_get.id_ev_type
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source, id_ev_type=typ).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        else:
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        # start = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_start.year, time_start.month, time_start.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        # end = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_end.year, time_end.month, time_end.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
        datas = [item.value for item in items]
        text = form.source_id.data
        dict_data = {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': text}
        return render_template('chart.html', form=form, **dict_data)
    else:
        source_id = form.source_id.data
        type_id = form.type_id.data
        source_get = EvSource.query.filter_by(description=source_id).first()
        source = source_get.id_ev_source
        items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
        datas = [item.value for item in items]
        text = form.source_id.data
        dict_data = {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': text}
        return render_template('chart.html', form=form, **dict_data)


class LogChartForm(FlaskForm):
    """Graph Form: Filter"""
    source_list = [source.description for source in EvSource.query.all()]
    type_list = [typ.description for typ in EvType.query.all()]
    type_list.append('All')
    source_id = SelectField(
        default=source_list[0],
        choices=source_list
    )
    type_id = SelectField(
        default=type_list[-1],
        choices=type_list
    )
    time_start = DateField(default=None, format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[Optional()])
    time_end = DateField(default=None, format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField('Apply')
```

Html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div style="width: 100%; display: grid; color: #272d3d;">
    <div style="background-color: #eaeaea; min-height: 50px; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;">
        <p style="margin: 10px 0 0 30px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.2;">Current system status: Graph</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 30px 5% 30px 5%; height: 50vh;">
        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            const labels = {{ labels | tojson }};
            const texts = {{ texts | tojson }};
            const data = {
              labels: labels,
              datasets: [{
                label: texts,
                backgroundColor: '#E22545',
                borderColor: '#E22545',
                data: {{ datas | tojson }},
              }]
            };
            const config = {
              type: 'line',
              data: data,
              options: { maintainAspectRatio: false }
            };
            const myChart = new Chart(
              document.getElementById('myChart'),
              config
            );
        </script>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div style="width: 100%; display: grid; color: #272d3d;">
            <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; background-color: #eaeaea; min-height: 50px; border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;">
                <p style="margin: 10px 0 0 30px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.2;">Filters</p>
                <div style="margin: 10px 30px 0 0; text-align: right;">
                    {{ form.submit(style="height: 30px; width: 140px; font-size: 16px; color: #fbfbfb; background-color: #272d3d; border: none; font-weight: 700;") }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="margin: 30px 5% 30px 5%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr; grid-column-gap: 80px">
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Signal source
                    </p>
                    {{ form.source_id(style="height: 25px; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Signal type
                    </p>
                    {{ form.type_id(style="height: 25px; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Period
                    </p>
                    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-column-gap: 20px">
                    {{ form.time_start(class= "datepicker", style="text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                    {{ form.time_end(class= "datepicker", style="text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I use a global data dictionary for plotting:

```py
def dict_chart():
    """Global Data Dictionary for Graph"""
    end = datetime.date.today()
    start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=28)
    start_time = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(start.year, start.month, start.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
    end_time = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(end.year, end.month, end.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
    items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=1).filter(Log.timestamp <= end_time, Log.timestamp >= start_time).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
    labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
    datas = [item.value for item in items]
    source_get = EvSource.query.get_or_404(1)
    text = source_get.description
    signal = 'Все'
    return {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': text, 'signal': signal, 'start': start, 'end': end}

DICT_DATA_CHART = dict_chart()

@app.route('/chart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chart_view():
    """Chart Page"""
    if USER_NAME == '':
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    global DICT_DATA_CHART
    form = LogChartForm(
        source_id=DICT_DATA_CHART['texts'],
        type_id=DICT_DATA_CHART['signal'],
        time_start=DICT_DATA_CHART['start'],
        time_end=DICT_DATA_CHART['end']
    )
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        source_id = form.source_id.data
        type_id = form.type_id.data
        time_start = form.time_start.data
        time_end = form.time_end.data
        start = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_start.year, time_start.month, time_start.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        end = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_end.year, time_end.month, time_end.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        source_get = EvSource.query.filter_by(description=source_id).first()
        source = source_get.id_ev_source
        if type_id != 'Все':
            typ_get = EvType.query.filter_by(description=type_id).first()
            typ = typ_get.id_ev_type
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source, id_ev_type=typ).filter(Log.timestamp <= end, Log.timestamp >= start).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        else:
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source).filter(Log.timestamp <= end, Log.timestamp >= start).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
        datas = [item.value for item in items]
        DICT_DATA_CHART = {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': source_id, 'signal': type_id, 'start': time_start, 'end': time_end}
        return redirect(url_for('chart_view'))
    return render_template('chart.html', form=form, user=USER_NAME, **DICT_DATA_CHART)
```